# whats A is representing in GPS co-ordinate point?

Tags: gps

I am getting GPS information from a device like this

```
052340.000,A
32.46275,N
75.310415,E
```

I know N is for north and E for east but what A is representing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the value, and some of the other comments, it is unlikely to be an altitude in meters. If this has been extracted from a GPGLL NMEA sentance, the value is time of fix, e.g. 05:23:40, as per the following

```
$GPGLL

Geographic Position, Latitude / Longitude and time.

eg2. $GPGLL,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,225444,A
    4916.46,N    Latitude 49 deg. 16.45 min. North
    12311.12,W   Longitude 123 deg. 11.12 min. West
    225444       Fix taken at 22:54:44 UTC
    A            Data valid


eg3. $GPGLL,5133.81,N,00042.25,W*75
               1    2     3    4 5
      1    5133.81   Current latitude
      2    N         North/South
      3    00042.25  Current longitude
      4    W         East/West
      5    *75       checksum

$--GLL,lll.ll,a,yyyyy.yy,a,hhmmss.ss,A
    llll.ll = Latitude of position
    a = N or S
    yyyyy.yy = Longitude of position
    a = E or W
    hhmmss.ss = UTC of position
    A = status: A = valid data
```

Comment: +1. I think you may have it there, the format (six digits with some fractional bit) and value (hours, minutes and seconds within range) fits a time perfectly. In fact, I'm so confident you're right, I obnoxiously editeds your answer :-) Hope you don't mind too much.

Answer (score 0):

Altitude. it would depend on the device as to what units it is. from the number shown in your example i would doubt it is meters, unless you are in an aeroplane.

more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Structure)

Comment: 50 kilometers would be a spacecraft, not a plane. Commercial aircraft top out at 40000ft, about 12km.

Comment: @Paxdiablo, quite right.  I'm guessing the value is actually the time of fix and not the height at all.